# Как почистить историю коммитов после слияния?

Tags: git, merge

Такой вопрос. Есть ветка "main". Что бы ее не засорять лишними комитами я создал ветку "work"  в которой работал и далее, переключившись в "main" командой "git merge work"  я слил ее с основной "main". Но все комиты, что я делал в "work" перешли в "main". Задача, что бы была чистая ветка "main" без промежуточных комитов не решена. Подскажите, как ее можно решить

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: сделайте вместо обычного слияния git merge --squash и git commit

Comment: **Кратко опишите вашу конкретную проблему в заголовке** - [ask]

Comment: Плюсую ключ `--squash`, он для этого и нужен собственно.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку коммиты уже попали в ветку `main`, то для избавления от ненужных можно сделать перебазирование.

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~N
```

где `N = количество коммитов в ветке work + 1`.

Будет открыт интерактивный режим перебазирования, вывод будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом (коммиты перечислены в обратном порядке относительно времени их создания):

```
pick 841862b Последний нужный коммит в main
pick e1088e2 Ненужный коммит из work
pick 634db7b Ненужный коммит 2 из work
pick d6154aa Законченная задача из work
```

а ниже будут приведены подсказки по доступным командам. Нас интересует команда `squash` - использовать коммит, но объединить его с предыдущим. Редактируем список выполняемых команд (редактирование доступно по нажатию клавиши `Insert`):

```
pick 841862b Последний нужный коммит в main
pick e1088e2 Ненужный коммит из work
squash 634db7b Ненужный коммит 2 из work
squash d6154aa Законченная задача из work
```

То есть мы сохраняем коммит `841862b` неизменным, и создаём новый коммит в виде комбинации изменений трёх последних коммитов. Выходим из режима редактирования и сохраняем результат (`Esc` + `:wq`). после этого будет предложено объединить сообщения коммитов:

```
# This is a combination of 3 commits.
# This is the 1st commit message:

Ненужный коммит из work

# This is the commit message #2:

Ненужный коммит 2 из work

# This is the commit message #3:

Законченная задача из work
```

Удаляем ненужные сообщения или перефразируем их и сохраняем результат:

```
# This is a combination of 3 commits.
# This is the 1st commit message:

Законченная задача
```

После этого все промежуточные коммиты не присутствуют в ветке `main`, однако изменения в них сделанные присутствуют в последнем:

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline
42ec8a78845ff54ce0ad65b2b7225b3523f18ad5 (HEAD -> main) Законченная задача
841862b28ce123fd9b7ada6731670cc76193e1fd Последний нужный коммит в main
```

**ВНИМАНИЕ!**
Перебазирование приводит к созданию нового коммита. Обратите внимание на хеши коммитов до перебазирования и после: `e1088e2`, `634db7b`, `d6154aa` до, и `42ec8a7` после. Никогда не делайте перебазирование, если уже отправили изменения в удалённый репозиторий.

Answer (score 0):

Копируете коммит в текущую ветку, как вариант:

```
$ git cherry-pick *hashCommit*
```

Да и вообще такая практика не очень распространена, если коммиты вам не нужны, то и не надо было их создавать.

Comment: Да и вообще такая практика, не очень распространена, если коммиты вам не нужны то и не надо было их создавать

Comment: Исходный вопрос немного о другом, а именно об _объединении нескольких коммитов_ (squash), а не об избирательном выборе конкретного коммита.

Comment: @Monteg, в этом случае все изменения, сделанные в промежуточных коммитах, не будут применены